# awk does not print line number

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have the following code

```
awk -v bookName="$bookName" -v authorName="$authorName" '/bookName:authorName/{print NR}' BookDB.txt
```

My bookDB.txt contains text with syntax as shown:

bookname:authorname:price

The code above aims to match exactly "bookname:authorname" and print out the line number where it match. However, it is not printing out anything.

I don't find anything wrong in the code syntax. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to use awk variables within `/ /`, which you can't do.

Change your condition to `$0 ~ bookName ":" authorName` to search the whole record `$0` for the pattern.

Alternatively, if the fields in your file are separated by `:`, you could also set the input field separator using `-F:` and then use string comparisons on the first two fields:

```
awk -F: -v book="$bookName" -v author="$authorName" '
    $1 == book && $2 == author{print NR}' BookDB.txt
```